# Enhance image manipulation (move & zoom) performance

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm moving and zooming a variable amount (between 1 and ~80) of images (110 x 110 px) simultanioulsy. Each of the displayed images is a bitmap loaded from disk into an WPF `Image` control. The input for the manipulation is acquired using touch manipulation events (`ManipulationDelta`).

As soon as I'm trying to manipulate more then just a few images (3 or 4) everything starts to get slow. How could I improve the performance of my solution?

For the manipulation I use the following code:

**Touch input:**

```
private void TouchManipulationContainer_ManipulationDelta(object sender, 
                                  ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    var scale = e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;
    panAllSelected(e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X, 
                   e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y, scale);
}

private void panAllSelected(double x, double y, double scale)
{
    foreach (var child in ImageGrid.Children)
    {
        if (child.GetType() == typeof(ImageDisplayContainer))
        {
            var tds = (child as ImageDisplayContainer);
            if (tds.IsSelected) tds.TouchDisplayControl.MoveAndZoom(x, y, scale);
        }
    }
}
```

**Image Manipulation:**

```
public void MoveAndZoom(double DeltaX, double DeltaY, double DeltaZoom)
{
    position.X += DeltaX;
    position.Y += DeltaY;

    scale += (DeltaZoom - 1.0);

    MovableImage.SetValue(ImageCanvas.LeftProperty, position.X);
    MovableImage.SetValue(ImageCanvas.TopProperty, position.Y);

    var x = MovableImage.GetValue(ImageCanvas.LeftProperty);
    var y = MovableImage.GetValue(ImageCanvas.TopProperty);
    Console.WriteLine(x + "; " + y + "; " + scale);

    if (scale != 1.0)
    {
        var sizeX = ImageCanvas.ActualWidth * scale;
        var sizeY = ImageCanvas.ActualHeight * scale;
        var size = Math.Max(sizeX, sizeY);

        MovableImage.Width = Math.Abs(size);
        MovableImage.Height = Math.Abs(size);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Grid ClipToBounds="True">
    <Canvas x:Name="ImageCanvas" Background="Black">
        <Image x:Name="MovableImage"
               Source="/ImageInspector3;component/Images/Data/Thumbnails/ImageViewer_Series1.png"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Does that mean you have a collection of images where only the selected ones are moved and scaled, whereas the others keep their size and position? Do images overlap each other afterwards? Please provide a bit more explanation about what you are trying to achieve and how the application should work.

Comment: Exaclty, I have a grid of images, just the selected ones should be manipulated. The images should not overlap, but should be clipped at the boundries of their cells.

Comment: Did you consider using a common RenderTransform? Put each image in a fixed size container with ClipToBounds=true, and then assign the same transform object (e.g. a MatrixTransform) to the RenderTransform property of all selected Image controls. Now you would only manipulate that single transform object without generating a new layout on each manipulation event.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion using RenderTransform. Now everything works really smooth! If you put that suggestion into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Take what Chris Eelmaa has posted, and improve it by using a single transform object for all selected images (e.g. a StaticResource or a view model property). Then you may accept his answer.

Comment: @Clemens: not sure how it would work if all the selected items share the same matrix. They would be positioned all in the same place.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa No, they won't. A RenderTransform would transform them relative to the position they get from their container's layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 3/4 objects and already slowing down, that sounds quite bad.

Clemens idea is not bad. Instead of `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties, you can try `MatrixTransform` (I've seen this used quite few times when dealing with touch events).

```
 <Image x:Name="MovableImage" 
        Source="...myPicture"
        RenderTransform="0 0 0 0.0 0 0" />
```

The way you can manipulate the `Matrix`:

```
var element = (Image)args.Source;
MatrixTransform xform = element.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
Matrix matrix = xform.Matrix;

ManipulationDelta delta = args.DeltaManipulation;
Point center = args.ManipulationOrigin;

matrix.ScaleAt(delta.Scale.X, delta.Scale.Y, center.X, center.Y);
matrix.Translate(delta.Translation.X, delta.Translation.Y);
xform.Matrix = matrix;
```

More links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff898416.aspx

http://blog.andreweichacker.com/2010/04/wpf-4-0-multitouch-manipulation/